# Partial fractions of $\frac{1}{x^5-x^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the following correct?

$$\frac{1}{(x^5-x^3)}=\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2-x)}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2-x)^2}+\frac{E}{x}$$

Comment: Note that $(x^5-x^3)=x^3(x+1)(x-1)$

Comment: but $(x^5-x^3)=(x^2-x)^2x$

Comment: $(x^2-x)^2=x^2(x^2-2x+1)=x^4-2x^3+x^2$...

Comment: Do NOT make the mistake of saying that $(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2$!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not,
notice that:

$$\frac{1}{x^5-x^3}=\frac{1}{x^3(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{A}{x^3}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x-1}+\frac{D}{x}+\frac{E}{x+1}=\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Does $(x^2-x)^2x = (x^4-x^2)x = x^5-x^3$?

Check the first equality.

Also, see: [Wikipedia » Partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition)

Answer (score -2):

This one is better : $$\frac{1}{(x^5-x^3)}=\frac{a}{(x-1)}+\frac{cx^2+dx+e}{(x^3)}+\frac{b}{x+1}$$
using identification, we find $$a=b=1/2, c=-1, d=0, e=-1$$
then $$\frac{1}{(x^5-x^3)}=\frac{1}{2(x-1)}+-\frac{x^2+1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)}$$

Comment: This is wrong , you need $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ too

Comment: Fractions in the partialfraction decomposition with a degree $n$ polynomial for the denominator will have a degree $<n$ polynomial for the numerator.  Factors which are repeated $n$ times will appear $n$ times as well, each of different powers.  I.e. you should not have had an $Ax$ for the first or third fractions, and the middle fraction should instead have been $\frac{Cx^2+Dx+G}{x^3}+\frac{Hx+I}{x^2}+\frac{J}{x}$

Comment: I think that $Cx$ should be $Cx^2$. Here is why: http://www.quickmath.com/webMathematica3/quickmath/algebra/partialfractions/basic.jsp#c=partial_fractions_basicpartialfractions&v1=1%2F(x%5E5-x%5E3)

Comment: Why above $x-1$ and $x+1$ it is not just A,B...? why Ax+B?